# How to automatically close NERDTree after a file has been opened?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

The file is opened with the 'return' key on the current tab or with the 't' key to open it on a new VIM tab.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try `:help nerdtreequitonopen`.

Answer (score 86):

Add the following to your .vimrc

```
let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `.vimrc`:

```
let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen='Value'
```

and Values :

```
 Value  | NERDTree Window Behavior
 -------+-------------------------------------------------------
 0      | No change
 1      | Closes after opening a file
 2      | Closes the bookmark table after opening a bookmark
 3(1+2) | Same as both 1 and 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `let NERDTreeCustomOpenArgs = {'file':{'keepopen': 0}}`