# How do I get NERDtree to automatically close after opening a file, whichever way I decide to open it?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

this question *may* seem like a duplicate of [How to automatically close NERDTree after a file has been opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239192/how-to-automatically-close-nerdtree-after-a-file-has-been-opened) (which has excellent answers), but it's not, I swear. I'd like to extend the question:

I'd love for NERDtree to close after I pick a file with `:e` or with `ctrlp.vim`
In such cases, NERDtree remains open regardless of the `let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen` value.

How do I get NERDtree to close after opening a file, whichever way I decide to open it?

Comment: Maybe this will help:
`:au BufNew * :NERDTreeClose<CR>`
this is an `autocommand` mapping, on each `BufNew` event it will call `NerdTreeClose` command. Probably this event won't suit you best, but there are a lot of events to choose from - [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html)